# ghost deploy using dokku: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, dokku, ghost

I'm trying to deploy Ghost (https://ghost.org/) to my server using dokku

I changed in config.js:

```
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: process.env.PORT
},
```

*also tried with 127.0.0.1*

Procfile:

```
web: npm start --production
```

git repository was just created only for deploy purposes (I use mercurial for development, and usually use hg-git extension)

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'deploy'
git remote add dokku dokku@myserver.net:ghost
git push dokku master
```

but when I do push, I receive:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)                                                      
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@myserver.net:ghost'
```

*P.S. I googled before post this question, other solutions don't work for me*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another git repository inside, I cloned theme for the blog using git

so it was counted as a submodule, that's what was blocking the push

I had to make commit inside the Theme first, and then commit the whole project